# Buildfailed : Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native and even I'm able to run my app in my simulator succesfully. But when i build the app I'm getting this error.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I even installed jetifier. But nothing worked fine..

for both `./gradlew bundleRelease` and `./gradlew assembleRelease` I'm getting the Error.
But for `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` I'm not getting erro BUT that apk is not working in a physical device. It simply crashes.